# Parse for Universal Apps

Tags: c#, parse-platform, windows-runtime, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

i'm trying to implement Parse push notification on Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime app)

searching around i found that you need to download the sdk from parse website and add the reference to Parse.dll and Parse.WinRT manualy.

i'm able to use the library, but when i try to subscribe to a channel after a while it throws an exception.

i'm not able to find a proper tutorial :(

anyway this is the line of code that reise the exception:

ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("testchannel");

and this is the stacktrace:

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.b__d(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.d__4.MoveNext()

**EDIT: After some test i have found that parse doesn't work on the windows phone emulator, as soon as i have tried the app on the phone it works perfectly**

**EDIT2: anyone know how to fix the emulator issue with parse?**

Comment: You should post your solution (edit) as an answer to this same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test i have found that parse doesn't work on the windows phone emulator, as soon as i have tried the app on the phone it works perfectly